# Why is PHP printing weird results in table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, echo

Im showing the results of a Mysql query with PHP in a table. So far so good.

Im my computer and several others the results output OK like this:

[image]

But the results in some computers output weird stuffs like this:

[image]

Some number are duplicate, others appear writed in letters ..

The script is the following:

```
<?php

require_once("../includes/psl-config.php");

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");  

    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Desde , date_add(Desde, INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS Hasta, W, C, 
CS, CD from ( SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT( yearweek(orders_header.created_at - INTERVAL 4 DAY) , ' Thursday'), '%X%V %W') as Desde,
 WEEK(orders_header.created_at - INTERVAL 4 DAY) as W, 
count(orders_header.id) as C, count(distinct `store_id`) as CS, count(distinct `dv_guy_id`) as CD
 FROM `orders_header` where delivered=1 and is_canceled=0 GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT( 
yearweek(orders_header.created_at - INTERVAL 4 DAY) , ' Thursday'), '%X%V %W')) as XX order by W 
desc");

if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $desde=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row[0]));
    $hasta=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row[1]));
      echo '<tr>
              <td class="text-center">Desde: '.$desde.' .. Hasta: '.$hasta.'</td>
              <td class="text-center" style="font-size:20px">'.$row[3].'</td>
              <td class="text-center" style="font-size:20px">'.$row[4].'</td>
              <td class="text-center" style="font-size:20px">'.$row[5].'</td>
            </tr>';
  }
}


?>
```

The only thing I can think about this is that this has to do with the calculation of dates in the query

Comment: Yes! I dont know why! is the same url and same page

Comment: Is there any JavaScript modifying the page?  Instead of relying on the screen images, post what's in the Page Source in the browser.  That should be the exact output from PHP.  If it's still incorrect output, check the results of manually running that exact database query on the data.

Comment: They also get different table headers. Can users choose to select a language on your site? Maybe they use a site-translation-service/-plugin?!

Comment: Maybe is the site translation! I going to check that!

Comment: This is not a problem with your site. It is a problem with the automatic translation in the user browsers

Comment: If it was me , I'd start over, focusing only on the sql.

Comment: There's a long way between SQL and a picture of the screen where data can be altered, but I'd start having a look at the generated HTML (as opposed to the rendered view). I'm pretty sure it's some fancy Chrome extension.

Comment: I solve this like @Dharman say: This is not a problem with your site. It is a problem with the automatic translation in the user browsers